# Can you open a Direct Message on Instagram's browser via a URL that uses Instagram ID or Username?

Tags: instagram

I am sending multiple Instagram direct messages and would like to pre-populate URLs that open up a direct message between me and my follower. I have the Instagram ID and usernames of each follower.

Currently, Instagram has its "inbox" at https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/.

When I manually create a direct message, it follows the following format: https://www.instagram.com/direct/t/[long numeric slug that seems randomly generated]

I'm curious if there's some other URL that would open up a chat initially, such as:
https://www.instagram.com/direct/[Instagram ID]
OR
https://www.instagram.com/direct/[Instagram Username]

Has anyone figured out a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Now you can create direct link to Instagram Inbox. Use link like this

https://ig.me/m/username

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there currently is no way to open a chat with someone using an url.

Comment: This seems more like a comment to me ^^. If you want to comment on a post, you should provide [actual answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to earn the reputation necessary to comment (which is 50, see [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))

Answer (score -1):

Use the link

```
https://instagram.com/m/username
```

and replace `username` as appropriate.